# Convert Lat Long (googlemaps) coordinates to ArcGIS mappoints

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, gis, latitude-longitude, arcgis

Hello I have a list of lats and longs which I would like to convert into points on `ArcGIS`.

When I use these coordinates and I can see their actual location on `Google` maps.

For the conversion on ArcGIS I use:

```
Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984
Projected Coordinate System:    WGS_1984_World_Mercator
```

But when I overlay them on `openstreetmap` (basemap) then their location in on different locations in the world map.

Do we know why this is happening? Am I doing something wrong on `ArcGIS`. I have followed the same process before and the data were displayed correctly.

Do we always have to use WGS_1984 for lats and longs?

A sample of coordinates that I would like to plot on a `googlemap` background are the following:

```
ID  Longitude   Latitude
-------------------------
1   45.49646    12.95288
2   44.4        12.1
3   44.23       8.56
4   44.22       8.34
5   44.21667    8.43333
```

I would appreciate if someone would guide me through the process on ArcGIS.

Comment: I'd recommend posting this on gis.stackexchange.com.  That site is supported by GIS professionals that could probably answer this.

Answer (score 0):

`WGS_1984_World_Mercator` ([EPSG:3395](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3395/)) is (possibly) not the right coordinate system.

If you make a new map document in ArcGIS, add the OpenStreetMap BaseMap and double-click 'Layers' in the ToC, you'll see that the document is set to `WGS84 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere)` ([EPSG:3857](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/)). While they're not (very) different, it might be enough to be producing your incorrect results.

Comment: Are some of these values truncated? Decimal degrees at 1 or 2 digit precision is pretty crude, although that shouldn't explain the alignment problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. Juffy i have used world mercator on lat long coordinates before and they were displayed correctly on OpenStreetmap. This is the time i only have issues. The only difference between the 2 datasets is that the current one covers only a small part of Europe while the previous one covered areas in the whole world. Ako the values are not truncated.